# Get message ID of the message sent by my bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I need to get the message id of the message my discord bot sends (it sends a rich embed)

Thanks

Comment: can you post what you have tried so far?

Comment: How about `Message.id` https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=id

Comment: @gratienasimbahwe Haven't really tried anything because there is not really any post showing what to do

Comment: @doniyor2109 I believe that gets the message ID of the message the user sent to activate the command

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you use [`TextChannel.send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send) (or any other kind of `.send` in Discord.js), it returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) that resolves with the message you just sent.
To work with that message, you can either use `await` to store it in a variable or use [`Promise.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) and pass the rest of your code as a function.

Here's an example:

```
// with async/await:
async function replyAndLog() {
  let sent = await message.reply("Your stuff..."); // this returns the message you just sent
  let id = sent.id; // you can get its ID with <Message>.id, as usually
  console.log(id);
}

// with <Promise>.then():
message.reply("Your stuff").then(sent => { // 'sent' is that message you just sent
  let id = sent.id;
  console.log(id);
});
```

Comment: Happy to hear that :)